# Is the following statement about rationals true or false?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, rational-numbers

I would like to know whether the following statement is true or false?

> > Suppose $A>B$, then there is a rational number between $A$ and $B$.

I need a proof if the statement is true. Please somebody explain to me how to do this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's true, but it has nothing to do with $A$ and $B$ being non-terminating decimals $-$ all you need is that $A \ne B$. (You _can_ use those decimal expansions to construct an explicit rational between $A$ and $B$, so perhaps that's what this question is really about.)

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so between $A$ and $B$ there is a rational number.

Choose $n\in \mathbb{N}$ with 
$$\frac{1}{n}<A-B.$$
and $k=\min\{m\in\mathbb{N}\mid \frac{m}{n}>B\}$. Then $B<\frac{k}{n}<A$.

Comment: How do I prove this?

Comment: I've added a proof for the density.

Comment: even with A and B being non-terminating decimals?