# How to prove the following statement about non-terminating decimals?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, rational-numbers

I was asked to prove the following statement:

> Suppose $A=.a_1a_2a_3...$ and $B=.b_1b_2b_3..$ are non-terminating decimals in standard form with $A>B$. There is a rational number between $A$ and $B$.

Can somebody explain this to me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Since it was **you** who was asked to prove it, could you share the work you've done so far?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I have not started. I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Hint: find the first (leftmost) digit which is different between the two.

Comment: @dxiv Should I choose some random decimals and let them be $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Additional to dxiv's hint you can be sure that there is a non-zero digit after every digit in a non-terminating decimal expansion. Slightly more difficult would be to prove that there is always a rational number between two rational numbers $a<b$.

Comment: I don't know why my comments are deleted, but I try it for one more time. You don't need all of the given information, for every pair of reals you can construct such a rational and this is showed for example in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030489/is-the-following-statement-about-rationals-true-or-false/2030495#2030495

Comment: @VadaCurry You can do that for practice. But in the end you'll need to work with arbitrary digits. Main point is that, since $A \gt B$ they can't both have all the same digits, so there will always be a smallest $k$ such that $a_k \ne b_k$. See how that can help.

Comment: I am curious. May I ask the downvoters (if they will ever return to see this question again) why the downvotes? It seems like a perfectly legitimate question. The OP might have not presented any work but sometimes one really is lost and doesn't understand even how to begin. Furthermore, in the comments above, the OP seems to be trying.

Answer (score 4):

Find the minimum value of $n$ such that $a_n>b_n$.

Note that $\forall_{k<n}:a_n=b_n$.

Therefore $A=0.\overline{a_1\dots a_n\dots}>0.\overline{a_1\dots a_n}>0.\overline{b_1\dots b_n\dots}=B$.

Note that $0.\overline{a_1\dots a_n}=\overline{a_1\dots a_n}/10^n$.

Therefore $A>\overline{a_1\dots a_n}/10^n>B$.

Since both $\overline{a_1\dots a_n}$ and $10^n$ are integers, $\overline{a_1\dots a_n}/10^n$ is rational.